# Excel Formula T.INV Calculation wrong using C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

In Excel **=T.INV(0.9,5)** returns the value '**1.475884**'.

Now I am using  the function of WorksheetFunction **TINV(0.9,5)** in C#.  But this gives me result **0.1321751752**.

So, in C# **TINV** result has too much different value than excel.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xl = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorksheetFunction wsf = xl.WorksheetFunction;
double result = wsf.TInv(0.9, 5);
```

Using another NuGet DLL also found same value as previous DLL:

```
var chart = new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
double resultTest = chart.DataManipulator.Statistics.TDistribution(.9, 5, true);
```

So, I need the same value as found on Excel Worksheet `**T.Inv**` function.

How can i get same T.INV value in c#.

can anyone help me to get the same result please?

Comment: Please insert all your code in code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code returns both the left-tailed and the two tailed inverse of the Student's t-distribution

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double value = 0.9;
    int degree = 5;

    var chart = new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
    double resultTest = chart.DataManipulator.Statistics.InverseTDistribution(value, degree);  
    Console.WriteLine(resultTest);

    //left-tailed 
    double result = alglib.invstudenttdistribution(degree, value);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

P.S. I used the invstudenttdistribution function available here [alglib.net](http://www.alglib.net/)

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you for your help but I am interested in matching T.INV only. So can I get any other  code or method for T.INV function  in asp.net so that I get 1.475884 as my answer.